# Do PHP form submissions cause the whole file to refresh?

Tags: php, html, ajax, xss

Will using `<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "post">` cause the whole page to refresh when the user clicks submit? Or just the PHP part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **page** usually **will reload after submitting a form to display the response that is received** after submitting the form.

To prevent that you got two ways:

1. Use `target=_blank` in your form tag

```html
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" target="_blank">
```

2. Use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the default action of form and then send data manually with `fetch` or if you use JQuery you might go with `ajax`. (I will go with fetch standard API)

```js
document.getElementByTagName("form")[0].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api';
  // The data we are going to send in our request
  const data = {
    name: 'Sara'
  }
  // The parameters we are gonna pass to the fetch function
  const fetchData = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
    headers: new Headers()
  }
  fetch(url, fetchData)
    .then(function() {
      // Handle response you get from the server
    });
});
```